# Mutually dependent constexpr constructors

Tags: constructor, dependencies, constexpr, forward-declaration

I have two classes, each constructible from the other.

Example:

```
class B;

class A{
 public:
  double val;
  constexpr A(B b): val(b.val){};
};

class B{
 public:
  double val;
  constexpr B(A a): val(a.val){};
};
```

I need to forward-declare `class B`, so A knows about it. When these constructors are not `constexpr`, I can move their definitions to a source file and it happily compiles.

However, to make it constexpr, they have to be defined in the header. `B` is ok to construct from `A`, because it sees the full definition of `A`. `A` cannot construct from `B` because it only sees a declaration, and therefore has no idea about `B::val`.

I'm left with only making `class B` `constexpr`. Is there a way to do it for both classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gcc I get the error (https://godbolt.org/z/qvP7absdr):

```
<source>:6:15: error: 'b' has incomplete type
    6 | constexpr A(B b) : val(b.val){};
      |             ~~^
<source>:1:7: note: forward declaration of 'class B'
    1 | class B;
      |       ^
<source>: In constructor 'constexpr A::A(B)':
<source>:6:11: error: invalid type for parameter 1 of 'constexpr' function 'constexpr A::A(B)'
    6 | constexpr A(B b) : val(b.val){};
      |           ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

So this fails because type `B` is incomplete when it is used it is the definition of the constructor `A::A(B b)`.

In order to deal with this we can wait until we have declared `B` fully before we define the constructor and use B.  Essentially, move the definition of the constructor out of class `A` and after class `B`

```cpp
class B;

class A{
 public:
  double val;
  constexpr A(B b);
};

class B{
 public:
  double val;
  constexpr B(A a): val(a.val){};
};

constexpr A::A(B b) : val(b.val){};
```

See an example without compilations issues:
https://godbolt.org/z/44fbcr8sh

Comment: Thank you. At the time of writing this question, I didn't realize I could separate the definition in the same file like that. This is the solution I ended up implementing, albeit, my B constructor was also moved outside for symmetry.